# need to add a clause

Tags: sql

With this query...

```
SELECT 
    Product, LengthInch, Sum(PieceCount) AS TotPcs, 
    WeekYear, SpecialReq, ControlRoll, 
    CASE WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CustNo END CustNum 
FROM 
    RMCutSumData 
GROUP BY 
    Product, LengthInch, WeekYear, SpecialReq, ProdGrade, 
    ControlRoll, 
    CASE WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CustNo END
HAVING 
    Product = 'W14X145' 
    AND ProdGrade = '992' 
    AND WeekYear = 615 
ORDER BY 
    LengthInch
```

The query above works great however: I need to add that

```
when SpecialReq IS NULL and CustNo = 1988 then 1988 else CustNo
```

I have tried everything I can think of and am blue in the face.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want your `Group by case` to be changed to also include the condition you mentioned above

Try this...

```
SELECT Product
    ,LengthInch
    ,Sum(PieceCount) AS TotPcs
    ,WeekYear
    ,SpecialReq
    ,ControlRoll
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL AND CUSTNO=1988
            THEN 1988
        WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE CustNo
        END CustNum
FROM RMCutSumData
where Product = 'W14X145'
    AND ProdGrade = '992'
    AND WeekYear = 615
GROUP BY Product
    ,LengthInch
    ,WeekYear
    ,SpecialReq
    ,ProdGrade
    ,ControlRoll
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL AND CUSTNO=1988
            THEN 1988
        WHEN SpecialReq IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE CustNo
        END

ORDER BY LengthInch
```

For Row based conditions, I would prefer to use `Where` instead of `Having`. I recommend the use of `Having` when you want to apply conditions on aggregates.